# EJB3.1 TimerService @Timeout current principal

Tags: java, authentication, timer, ejb-3.1

I have a question regarding authentication and the TimerService @Timeout annotation :

In our application users can schedule tasks to be performed at a given interval, They select from a list of tasks, each task is associated to a specific EJB in the application. When the user presses the save button a new timer is added to the Timer service, when the @Timeout method is invoked, a method on the EJB that the user specified is invoked from with the @Timeout method

When the timeout method is ivoked by the Timerservice, the current principal is "ANONYMOUS". This is problematic if you need to invoke any protected EJB's from within the timout method. Is it possible to change the current principal and role to the same principal and role as user that created the timer?

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class TestEJB 
{

    @Resource
    SessionContext context;
    @Resource
    TimerService timerService;

    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer) throws Exception {
        //Get the current username
        System.out.println(context.getCallerPrincipal().getName());
    }

    public void createScheduledTimer(ScheduleExpression e,String timerId) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, EJBException {
        TimerConfig tc = new TimerConfig();
        tc.setInfo(timerId);
        tc.setPersistent(true);
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(e, tc);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did this in Glassfish. In our case we have a generic Timer bean that can run any of several tasks, rather than a bean per task as you are doing, but the concept is the same.

What we ended up doing is we record the user when the task is submitted, then we leverage Glassfish's specific ProgramaticLogin facility to log the user back in when the timer starts. That way the entire EJB security context is setup appropriately for the user and the task.

Comment: @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer){ProgrammaticLogin programmaticLogin = new ProgrammaticLogin();
programmaticLogin.login(userName,password);

Comment: Hi, Thanks a million, this is exactly what I was lookin for, we are running our application on glassfish as well, I couldnt find a lot of examples on programatic login, does your implementation look similar to the below:
ProgrammaticLogin programmaticLogin = new ProgrammaticLogin();
programmaticLogin.login(userName,password);

Comment: Yes, that's what we use. I should note that we're using a custom Realm for our implementation (normally Glassfish just comes with a file, jdbc, and an LDAP realm). The other thing we do is pass in signed token instead of a password that the Realm can detect so as to know "it's from us", that way we do not need to have the users actual password in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

try to use @RunAs. check the example here: http://www.shareyourwork.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/using_runas_in_ejb_3

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, the RunAs annotation does sort out part of the problem, however, is it possible to invoke an EJB from within the timout method as a specific user? thereby if the invoked EJB calls context.getCallerPrincipal() it will return the username?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using 3.1 Stateful Session Beans are supported for Timers. Try annotating your bean with `@Stateful` rather than `@Singleton`. Then try getting the username in your `createScheduledTimer` method. Store it as a private field, and then access it in the @Timeout method.

Comment: SFSB don't support timers.  You might be able to hold a reference to the SFSB, but it depends on whether the timer will fire before the SFSB times out.

Comment: I thought in 3.1 support was added to them?
From the JSR: EJB Timer Service enhancements to support cron-like scheduling,  deployment-time timer creation, and stateful session bean timed objects.

Comment: Support for SFSB was in the initial JSR 318 proposal, but the final release says (section 18.2) says: "Timers can be created for stateless session beans, singleton session beans, message-
driven beans, and 2.1 entity beans[94]. Timers cannot be created for stateful session beans[95]."